# Error configurating remote node-red module

Tags: node-red

I've been traing to configure the remote access node but the following error is displayed:

Cannot find module 'C:\Users\HP.node-red\node_modules\node-red-contrib-remote\nodes/package.json'

Require stack:

- C:\Users\HP.node-red\node_modules\node-red-contrib-remote\nodes\remote-commons.js
- C:\Users\HP.node-red\node_modules\node-red-contrib-remote\nodes\remote-config.js
- C:\Users\HP\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\node-red\node_modules@node-red\registry\lib\loader.js
- C:\Users\HP\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\node-red\node_modules@node-red\registry\lib\index.js
- C:\Users\HP\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\node-red\node_modules@node-red\runtime\lib\nodes\index.js
- C:\Users\HP\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\node-red\node_modules@node-red\runtime\lib\index.js
- C:\Users\HP\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\node-red\lib\red.js
- C:\Users\HP\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\node-red\red.js

I installed the remote node-red module twice because I though that it was an instalation error.

Comment: This appears to be a bug in the `node-red-contrib-remote`. It assumes that there will only ever be one instance of `/nodes` in it's path which is dangerous. Issue raised https://github.com/Looking4Cache/node-red-contrib-remote/issues/8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just changed the node to the suggestion of hardillb. Please try it again after the update to Version 1.3.2.

Comment: Works just fine thanks